# Java/Swing Print text from a child thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, text

I have a swing Frame displayed, with a button to start a thread :

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    private static Frame frame= null;
    public static Frame getFrame(){
        return frame== null? frame= new Frame(): frame;
    }

    Thread worker;
    JTextArea  textarea = new JTextArea();
    JButton b = new JButton();

    Frame(){
        frameinstance = this;
        b.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            worker = new Thread(new myWorker());
            worker.start();
        });
        //...
    }
}
```

The thread looks like :

```
public class myWorker implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
        //Do some work
        Frame.getFrame().textArea.append("Some work has been done");
        //Do some work
       Frame.getFrame().textArea.append("Some work has been done");
        //etc...
    }

}
```

But the text actually does not appears as work progress.

Comment: This does not look like actual Code, as there is no space between "myWorker" and "implements". How does this even compile? What is "Global"? Is getFrame a function? Then why has it no brackets "(" and ")"? If it is not a function, why is it called getFrame? Furthermore, you are leaving out sections of the code, so we don´t know what is going on there. I think you should revisit and edit your question, especially your code. Otherwise I don´t think you will get an answer, sorry to say.

Comment: I did some change from my project to be as short and precise as possible. I corrected errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing components should only be updated on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Most Swing components are not thread-safe and updating them in other threads can have unpredictable behavior.

You can use SwingUtilities.invokeLater (to schedule the update and continue) or SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait (to block until the event is processed) to update the UI.

For example:

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->Frame.getFrame().textArea.append("Some work has been done"));
```